# Как можно опубликовать картинку на сайт WordPress? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, thumbnails

Есть скрипт который удалённо публикует статьи на сайт под управлением WordPress.

Вот скрипт:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost

client = Client('http://localhost/xmlrpc.php', 'admin', 'password')

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'Это заголовок поста...'
post.content = 'Это текст поста...'
post.post_status = 'publish'
post.excerpt = 'Это анонс!'
post.thumbnail = ''
post.id = client.call(NewPost(post))
```

Как мне опубликовать к этому посту картинку из файла?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [этому](https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/blob/7ac0a6e9934fdbf02c2250932e0c026cf530d400/tests/test_media.py#L35) можно загрузить картинку в хранилище WP и получить `attachment_id`.

а после используйте `post.thumbnail = attachment_id`

Comment: Хорошо, а как можно получить attachment_id?

Comment: первая строчка ответа